# InteractiveViewer in SliverAppBar : prevent from responding to scroll (flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

**I have a an InteractiveViewer (containing an image) in a SliverAppBar (inside a NestedScrollView). Is it possible de prevent the SliverAppBar from responding to scroll ?**

**Context: **
The reason I used this is the following :

- in the body of the NestedScrollView, I have a list of images that I can select, inside a GridView.
- in the SliverAppBar, I display the image selected in an InteractiveViewer so that I can pan an scale the image.
  The SliverAppBar is floating/snapping so that each time I scroll up, the SliverAppBar appears, displaying the selected image.

(For those using Instagram, I'm trying to emulate their way of uploading pictures in "Create new post".)

**The problem I have is that when I try to pan up and down in my InteractiveViewer, Flutter thinks I'm willing to scroll**. I don't have this issue when I pan left/right or if I scale this image (pinch fingers).

I already tried to set NestedScrollView physics to NeverScroll but doesn't seem to be enough (as mentionned here : [how-can-i-stop-the-scroll-in-sliverappbar-flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73966133/how-can-i-stop-the-scroll-in-sliverappbar-flutter))

Any ideas ? Is that even possible ? Maybe it is possible with another widget ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: have you tried DraggableScrollableSheet?

Comment: @Boseong I'm not sure this widget can help me, it's not really the behavior I want in my case. But maybe I'm missing something ? How would you use it to match my case ?